# SQL request. How to make it work faster?

Tags: sql-server

I have sql request which take to much time to execute, any suggestions to make it faster?

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME; 
DECLARE @TwoWeeksAgo 
DATETIME; SET @Today = GETDATE();
SET @TwoWeeksAgo = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()); 
SELECT TOP ${selectSalesByMall} s.title, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleid) as mostViewPeriod14Days, s.guid, br.title as brand, s.id as saleId, stm.mallId
FROM dbo.Sales s  
INNER JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands br ON s.BrandId = br.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.SaleView sv2 on sv2.id = sv.id and sv2.userId = ${user['userID']} 
WHERE sv.Date 
BETWEEN @TwoWeeksAgo 
AND @Today 
AND sv2.id IS NULL 
AND s.isActive = 1
AND stm.mallId = ${user['mallId']}
AND br.id != ${user['favBrand']['brandId']}
AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT uess.saleID FROM dbo.UsersEmailsSalesSent uess WHERE uess.userID = ${user['userID']})
GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid, br.title, s.id, stm.mallId 
ORDER BY mostViewPeriod14Days DESC
```

Comment: Are indexes in place? Show us execution plan :)

Comment: I am using mac os x. I don't have such a tool.

Comment: What GUI do you use?

Comment: `${selectSalesByMall}` is not valid T-SQL. Please tell us the whole story

Comment: I am using node js sever. This is ${selectSalesByMall} dynamic variable

Comment: I am using async waterfall to pass the data. And then async.eachLimit function to grab the data in js array.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the issue is in the SQL and not in your processing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one improvement could be changing the "not in" to "not exists":

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME; 
DECLARE @TwoWeeksAgo 
DATETIME; SET @Today = GETDATE();
SET @TwoWeeksAgo = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()); 
SELECT TOP ${selectSalesByMall} s.title, s.imageUrl, count(sv.saleid) as mostViewPeriod14Days, s.guid, br.title as brand, s.id as saleId, stm.mallId
FROM dbo.Sales s  
INNER JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands br ON s.BrandId = br.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.SaleView sv2 on sv2.id = sv.id and sv2.userId = ${user['userID']} 
WHERE sv.Date 
BETWEEN @TwoWeeksAgo 
AND @Today 
AND sv2.id IS NULL 
AND s.isActive = 1
AND stm.mallId = ${user['mallId']}
AND br.id != ${user['favBrand']['brandId']}
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT uess.saleID FROM dbo.UsersEmailsSalesSent uess WHERE uess.userID = ${user['userID']} and  s.id=uess.saleID)
GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid, br.title, s.id, stm.mallId 
ORDER BY mostViewPeriod14Days DESC
```